# In a source code, I typed it in and got: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

image = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])


gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


plt.imshow(gray, cmap="gray")
plt.show()


edges = cv2.Canny(gray, threshold1=30, threshold2=100)


plt.imshow(edges, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

It doesn't work and displays the message above when I type it as instructed in the tutorial linked here. https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/canny-edge-detection-opencv-python
The full message is

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you are on linux like ubuntu need to install thinker from terminal

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

on mac

```
xcode-select --install
brew uninstall python
brew install python --with-tcl-tk
```

Comment: What if I use windows?

Answer (score 0):

try to install tkinter in terminal using pip or conda install tkinter